# How to redirect output to a file in C?

Tags: c, file, stdout

I am trying to, in C:

1. Read data from a file
2. Manipulate the data
3. Write manipulated data to another file

In the assignment requirements, it says to compile and run the program with the following commands:

```
gcc -o name name.c 
./name inputFileName.ext > outputFileName.ext
```

I am unfamiliar with the " > " command.  I have a couple of questions:

1. Online, it says that " > " redirects command output to a file, and I'm not sure exactly what "command output" means.  I'm redirecting the output from my name.c file to the outputFileName.ext file. Does command output mean stdout? If so, which C keyword would I use to write information to the outputFileName.ext file from name.c as stdout?
2. When I open and read my input file, I need to access the file that was passed in from the command line. Does the " > " character count as another command line argument? Can I still access inputFileName.ext from main() with the statement " argv[1] " ?

Comment: The `>` (stdout redirection) and `|` (pipe) operators are handled by your shell or command-interpreter, not your program.

Comment: Ok.  Can I still access command line arguments by indexing into argv[ ] if I use the stdout redirection operator? And how would I print something to stdout in C?  I'm on UNIX.

Comment: If you read the documentation about the [*command shell*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)) (such as *`bash`* or *`csh`*, etc.) you'll see that your program can be very simple because most of the instructions for your assignment can easily be carried out by a command shell.  Wikipedia has a lot of helpful information about these as well.

Comment: Some functions, such as `printf()` and `puts()`, write to `stdout`.  Others can be told to write to `stdout` with an explicit argument — `fprintf()` and `fputs()`, for example.  Note that neither the `>` nor the file name after is passed to your program; it has no idea where its output is going.  It just writes to its standard output and lets the system deal with where that goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Online, it says that `>` redirects command output to a file, and I'm not sure exactly what "command output" means.

"command output" refers to the `stdout` (Standard Output) stream of the program.

<sub>Do note that some shell commands are not separate programs but are actually [shell builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html), though they'll still support output redirection. On Windows, most shell commands (like `dir` and `del`) are built-ins whereas on Linux/BSD/etc most shell commands are separate programs (like `ls` and `mkdir`)</sub>

If your program calls `puts( "foobar" );` then running `./name` from Bash will display "foobar" in your terminal emulator. But if you run `./name > file.txt` then the "foobar" text will be written to `file.txt` and it will not be displayed in your terminal emulator.

Try it with the `ls` command, for example: `ls -al > files.txt`. This works on Windows too (`dir /s > files.txt`).

> I'm redirecting the output from my `name.c` file to the `outputFileName.ext` file. Does command output mean stdout?

Yes.

> If so, which C keyword would I use to write information to the outputFileName.ext file from name.c as stdout?

You don't. This is a shell/OS feature and is not part of C.

Answer (score 1):

Let's clarify a few things:

1. `>`, `<` and a few other symbols (that are not relevant to your question) are control operators for your command line interpreter (a.k.a the shell). When the shell sees any of those, it assumes the command line arguments to your program are now finished. So in your case, your program will have `argc=2` and `argv = ["name ", "inputFileName.ext"]`.
2. The "redirection" thing means that whatever your program would normally write to the screen via the `stdout` (which is ulitized by default when calling `printf()` `putchar()`, `puts()`) will be written to the filename that comes after `>`. Your pogram is completely unaware of this fact. In your code, you should just assume you are printing on the screen. It is the responsibility of the one who executes the command to perform the redirection. (Also: "outputFileName.ext" does not need to exist, it will be created if it doesn't, but the redirection **will override anything previously written in that file, so take extra care not to redirect to a .c file by accident or to your results of your previous execution, if you need them both**)
3. `<` (not in your question, but closely related) works the opposite way around as you would imagine, with the program reading input from that file rather than from the keyboard. (obviously the file needs to exist now)

For the second part of your question, you can (and should) still access the name of the input file via the contents of `argv[1]`. You will open the file and read from it via some of the C functions that takes a file descriptor as an argument (like `fscanf()`, `fgets()`, `getline()`).

Finally, are you sure the command given to you is

```
./name inputFileName.ext > outputFileName.ext
```

and not

```
./name < inputFileName.ext > outputFileName.ext
```

?

The latter uses redirection both for input and for output, and you should not do anything different when reading, just read normally from `stdin`.